# Different TLS protocols per server in Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, openssl, debian

I configured Nginx for two TLS virtualhost 'example.one' and 'example.two' with two different certficates.

I need to setup TLS1.0+ for the first one and only TLS1.2 for the second one. However the second one (example.two) configuration ignores ssl_protocols directive and takes ssl_procolols from first server directive.

So both server directive uses the first configured ssl_protocols directive.

```
server {
    listen          443 default_server ssl spdy;
    server_name     example.one;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_certificate         /certs/cert-for-example.one.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /certs/privkey-for-example.one.pem;


    # another ssl_* directives ...
} 

server {
    listen          443 ssl spdy;
    server_name     example.two;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;

    ssl_certificate         /certs/cert-for-example.two.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /certs/privkey-for-example.two.pem;

    # another ssl_* directives ...
}
```

I don't want to use SSL3 so the TLS SNI should work fine. And I don`t care about clients without TLS SNI support.

Only relevent information, i found is [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254016,254673#msg-254673). It says, Openssl is responsible.

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is there a workaround for this ?
(Except separate IP adress for server directive, but I don`t wanna go back to Stone Age)

I use Nginx/1.6.2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Here's the Nginx [bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/676). Both it and its [duplicate](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/844) are closed as _wontfix_. The workaround mentioned there is the one @Anton submitted below.

Answer (score 5):

It's how ssl works. SSL creates connection first and then does SNI. Nginx will pick up one ssl settings (such as in the default server config) to create the ssl connection. If that config doesn't specify some ssl protocol, that protocol won't be used at all.

So basicly the "per server ssl protocols" won't work as it looks like.

You may try to specify the union set of ssl protocols in the default server config and disable some of them in every server config. I tried this and it worked. But I didn't test every possible case.

You may see the discussion here: http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2014-November/045733.html

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, there are a possible to restrict TLS protocol version using `ssl_ciphers` directive. Supplying TLSv1.2 specific cipher suites will effectively prevent handshake for lower TLS versions. So, for above example,

```
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
```

instead `ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in nginx. I also posted this answer on https://serverfault.com/a/827794/318927

It's always only using the `ssl_protocols` directive from the first `server` block and ignoring any following `server` blocks. In my case I have many virtual servers running on the same instance, so I used the `nginx -T` command to display the full combined config to figure out which server block was the "first" since I have split it up into many separate config files.

At time of writing I'm trying this on Ubuntu 14.04.5 with nginx installed from the `ondrej/nginx` PPA.
Specifically I'm running nginx 1.10.2 built with OpenSSL 1.0.2j.

Output of `nginx -V`

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8xB1_y/nginx-1.10.2/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8xB1_y/nginx-1.10.2/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8xB1_y/nginx-1.10.2/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8xB1_y/nginx-1.10.2/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-8xB1_y/nginx-1.10.2/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

As a workaround for you I suggest trying the answer by Anton:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511119/1446479

Answer (score 4):

#### Root level (nginx.conf)

Include all the TLS versions in `ssl_protocols` and, at the same time, exclude `ssl_ciphers` of obsolete TLS versions trough openssl filter:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3;
ssl_ciphers EECDH:!eNULL:!aNULL:!TLSv1.1:!TLSv1:!SSLv3;
```

filter meaning - ephemeral keys exchanged by elliptic DH, only with encryption, only with auth, no obsolete TLS versions.

A+ score on ssllabs.com (*but it's not only about ciphers*), works fine with windows 7, must work both with ECDSA and RSA certs.

#### Site level (sites-enables/weaksite)

Return-back ssl_ciphers for necessary obsolete TLS versions:

```
ssl_ciphers EECDH:!eNULL:!aNULL:!RC4:!3DES:!SSLv3;
```

filter meaning - ephemeral keys exchanged by elliptic DH, only with encryption, only with auth, **allow TLS1+ versions** without RC4 and 3DES weak algorithms.

#### *Additional info*

Get list of ciphers by filter:

`openssl ciphers -v 'EECDH:!eNULL:!aNULL:!TLSv1.1:!TLSv1:!SSLv3' | column -t`

Get supported protocols and ciphers directly from web-server:

`nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.example.com`

OpenSSL filters explained:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html

Nginx guys washing their hands:

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254016,254673#msg-254673

Answer (score 0):

Do you use nginx from Dotdeb packages? If yes, in my opinion it is bug in Dotdeb version of nginx-common package in version 1.6.x.

I had similar configuration in ubuntu (nginx **1.6.2-1~dotdeb.0**, openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.20) and I could not access my website using TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2. Configuring:

```
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
```

made my website unavailable. Downgradnig nginx to version 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1 from default repositories resolved my problem, now TLSv1.2 works again. So in my opinion your problem is not about "using different ssl_protocoles" but about "using TLSv.1.1 and TLSv1.2 in nginx 1.6.x~dotdeb".

https://www.dotdeb.org/2014/06/30/nginx-1-6-0-has-been-updated-for-wheezy-and-squeeze/#comment-32895

Answer (score -1):

Server name is determined from the request (either from TLS extension if ServerNameIndication is supported and present or even from HTTP request). So it's not possible at handshake time or before it to know what server the client connects to and consequently what settings to use.

Update: [Here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6068943#1161939) the person from nginx team explains why this is not possible (for the exact reason I have written about).

Comment: I think there is server name presented in ClientHello packet (TLS 1.0+ with SNI support), so IMHO there should be no problem to determine correct 'server' directive and relevant 'ssl_protocols' directive.

Comment: @ZZromanZZ that's only about TLS with SNI. If you re-read my answer, I mentioned this explicitly. If you configure SSL 2.0 for one server and SSL 3.0 for another server, how should NGINX deal with this?

Comment: @Khanna111GauravKhanna both of you are not.

Comment: The op is concerned with tls1 and above.

Comment: @Khanna111GauravKhanna So what? OP's concern doesn't have anything to do with the way the protocol works and the way nginx works (not mentioning that the whole question is off-topic for StackOverflow).

Comment: I am interested how the protocol works and based on my knowledge I believe, this configuration should work. I guess, I should ask more generally: Is possible to have different TLS protocols for different server names (in Nginx) ?

Comment: @ZZromanZZ We have description of SSL/TLS here: https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1948.php?page=3 . *specially* crafted server-side TLS module would parse the initial request and decide how to act, but when it comes to OpenSSL and nginx I am sure that this is not done for the reason of having very little sense.

Comment: The desired host name is known immediately at the start of the handshake by simple peeking the data in the connecting client. Regardless of it's SNI or not, the Hello Server message you can discover in the peeked data shows the requested host. How else would they start a handshake for a specific host without anyone knowing what host? Magic?