# How to I override nginx ssl protocols?

Tags: ssl, nginx, protocols, config

I am web developer using nginx 1.6.2 ver using openssl 1.0.2h
I manage a lot of domains.
And very interested in security.

So My default nginx ssl setting is right here.
default.conf

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name localhost;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/SSL/***.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/SSL/***.key;

ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

location ~ {
    root    /etc/nginx/html;
    index   index.php;
    return 470;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/error_config;
}

}
```

as you can see, I used only ssl_protocols TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 
and I want to one of domains, **getssltest.ga**
Want to use only TLSv 1.1 & TLSv 1.2
But I tried to change virtual host configure file any way.
However, just adding 'ssl_protocols   TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;' doesn't validate.
like above this.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name getssltest.ga www.getssltest.ga;

    ssl_protocols   TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      **;
    ssl_certificate_key  **;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ssl_config;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

I can not find the way. ( I could check the protocols in here https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=getssltest.ga)

How can I override ssl_protocol to one of my virtual hosts?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can look it into documentation http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html, configuration should be how that:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         getssltest.ga www.getssltest.ga;
    ssl_certificate     *;
    ssl_certificate_key *;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is not applied to virtual host!

Comment: It's how ssl works. SSL creates connection first and then does SNI. Nginx will pick up one ssl settings (such as in the default server config) to create the ssl connection.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213607/different-tls-protocols-per-server-in-nginx